# How to get path of scripts in subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am facing one problem. I have this scripts structure:

```
| - folder1
|     |-script1.py
|     |-folder2
|     |     |-script2.py
```

script2 contain code:

```
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
print('full path =', os.path.abspath(pathname))
path_test = os.path.abspath(pathname)
```

I need to refer to path of script2.py because I have there test data. But after running script1.py my code described above returns path of script1.py.
How to print path of script2.py if it is launched by script1.py

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in variable `__file__` instead:

```
pathname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__file__):

> `__file__` is to be the “path” to the file unless the module is built-in (and thus listed in `sys.builtin_module_names`) in which case the
>   attribute is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module

**Ex:**

```
import os

script1Path = os.path.dirname(__file__)  
script2Path = os.path.join(script1Path, "folder2", "script2.py")
print(script2Path)
```